# Firebase OTP only works in some devices - Swift 4

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, swift4, one-time-password

I am using firebase authentication in my device. I have followed every steps in firebase documentation. The OTP works in the devices that I used for testing purpose. But when I download the app from AppStore, It does not work. Please help me to get rid of this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is way too broad and unanswerable. How would we know what the issue is without seeing your code or understanding anything about the actual problem? Please take a moment and review [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimum and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post some code, provide some details and we’ll take a look.

Comment: From the Help section here on SO *When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem, Complete – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem in the question itself, Verifiable – Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem*. If you want help, you will need to include code and outline the steps needed to reproduce the issue. The code in the link works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

There were 2 things wrong with what I was done.

1. When I created SSL certificate (For push notification) from App Ids under 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles' tab in developer.apple.com, The certificate was not created for production. So I created one for production.

[image]

2. I forgot to create APNs key. So I created APNs key from Keys under 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles' tab in developer.apple.com. Then I uploaded it in the firebase App (console.firebase.google.com). After you select your project, you can find a gear icon in the firebase website. Select project settings from there and click on the cloud messaging tab. And there you can find the option to upload APNs certificate.